# Magento Collection get clients by payment method

Tags: magento, methods, collections, filter, payment

I would like to know if anyone already coded a Magento Collection to get the customer name by the payment method? I used the code bellow and now I have the payment method that I need, now I just have to get the client's first and last name. Thank you all for the help.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_payment_collection')
                                               ->addFieldToSelect('*');

  foreach ($collection as $method) {
      if ($method->getMethod() == "mundipagg_boleto") {
           print $method->getMethod()."<br>";
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_payment_collection')
    ->addFieldToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter('method', "mundipagg_boleto");

  foreach ($collection as $orderPayment) {
      $orderId = $orderPayment->getParentId();
      $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
      $customerId = $order->getCustomerId();
  }
```

After that you can load customer's model by customerId

Comment: Thanks a lot Aleksandr, this was very helpful! I'll only make some adjustments cause i have to show the payment method with the name of the customer. Considering it, I'll only add a foreach to get the payment method title, and print it at the end.